# How to use a .jar from Command Line without typing full path

Tags: java, bash, jar, classpath

I downloaded example.jar and I can type `java -jar example.jar` from within the directory where it is located and it works.

The problem is that I need to be able to call it from elsewhere without typing the full path. Is it possible?

I tried adding it to $CLASSPATH like this:
`export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Path/to/Directory:/Path/to/Directory/example.jar` with no success.

Comment: Write a shell script, put that somewhere accessible from within the `PATH` element; use the full path to the Jar from within the script instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Option 1. Using the CLASSPATH you have set, **however** you would have to specify the fully qualified main-class from the jar

```
java com.mypackage.MyMain
```

As long as `com.mypackage.MyMain` is on the `CLASSPATH` and contains a valid `main` method, that will run it.

Option 2. Create a bash shell script to run it (note that this is really providing the full path to the `java` command)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export JARFILE="/Path/to/Directory/example.jar"
java -jar $JARFILE
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about creating another script for calling it, but I was getting mad about the CLASSPATH thing. I am not sure I understood your explanation. How should I know the name of the main class file?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro Check the [Main-Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) in the manifest

Comment: Ok, I now know the main: `com.vftlite.main.Menu` what now?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro Put that jar file in your CLASSPATH. Then `java com.vftlite.main.Menu`

Comment: I tried it yesterday and didn't work, now is working. Thanks